# getText wont work on a JTextField for some reason

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, gettext

Here is my code
Its asking to me set changeName to a static variable.  This wouldnt make sense because I'm trying to capture user input.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import CourseProject.General.exitApp;

public class Options extends JPanel{

    private JLabel changeLabel;
    private JTextField changeName;
    private JButton setName;
    private JButton exitButton;

    public Options(){
        GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        super.setLayout(gridbag);
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

        changeLabel = new JLabel("Change Company Name:");
        changeName = new JTextField(10);
        setName = new JButton("Set New Name");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");       

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(changeLabel, c);        

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;    
        add(changeName, c);     

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        add(setName, c);
        setName.addActionListener(new setNameAction());


        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;    
        add(exitButton, c);
        exitButton.addActionListener(new exitApp());
        exitButton.setSize(40,40);

    }
    static class setNameAction implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String str = "";
            str = changeName.getText();
        }
    }

    static class exitApp implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm specifically having a problem with this part of the code

```
static class setNameAction implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String str = "";
        str = changeName.getText();
    }
}
```

Its asking to me set changeName to a static variable.  This wouldnt make sense because I'm trying to capture user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inner class is declared `static`...

```
static class setNameAction ...
```

Remove the `static` reference from the class declaration if you want to be able to reference the instance fields of the outer class...

Otherwise you will be required to pass an instance of `Options` or `JTextField` to the `setNameAction` class.

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: lol thats what I get for trying to cut corners by copying and pasting without really knowing what it is that im doing at me level.  Thanks!

Comment: @helloWorldIsAlliKnow Welcome to my world ;)